# Excel sumproduct problem to get the revenue for the year

Tags: excel

[Spreadsheet with data (TB tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g1aX.png)

[Summary tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFz8C.png)

I am trying to get the revenue for the year to date in the Summary tab . I did this but it doesn't work:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((TB!A:A="IS-1*")*(Months<=E2)*(TB!C5:N41))
```

[Summary tab with codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2B6o.png)

[Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfhoT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need the first range to be as long as the sum range and the second range to be as wide, so this will work:

`=SUMPRODUCT((TB!A$5:A$41="IS-1*")*(Months<=E$2),TB!C$5:N$41)`

....as long as Months = `TB!C4:N4`

You could also use a lookup type formula to get the relevant code, making the formula "draggable", e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((TB!A$5:A$41=INDEX(Summary!A:A,MATCH(B5,Summary!B:B,0)))*(Months<=E$2),TB!C$5:N$41)`

Comment: It still doesn't work, you download the spreadsheet , just Google excel sumproduct exercise and look for xls file with the name exercise 9 it's from excel-skills.Co. uk .....when I put your first solution in I get "-" in the cell. sorry Google excel sumif exercises not sumproduct and you'll get the spreadsheet

Comment: "doesn't work" is subjective. There's no error therefore the formula is working, "-" or zero is a valid result. What value did you put in E2?

Comment: The value I put in E2 =months but I did a drop down list